# When clicking on a button inside another button, the functions for both buttons are run

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have `show-button` that, when clicked, expands and shows some text and a `collapse-button`:

```html
<button id='show-button'>
    <p>Test</p>
    <button id='collapse-button'></button>
</button>
```

When `show-button` is clicked, it expands and shows the paragraph and the collapse button. When the `collapse-button` is clicked, it collapses back to the original size where it's all hidden.

The problem is the following:

When I click on the `collapse-button`, the event listener for `click` is run and everything collapses. However, for some reason, the event listener of the `show-button` is also triggered and everything is shown again. A loop. You can show but never collapse it again.

How can I make sure that when `collapse-button` is pressed, `show-button` isn't also triggered?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the "click" function you can stop the propagation of the event so it will not reach the other components 
`event.stopImmediatePropagation();`

Comment: Thanks it worked. Visual Studio Code, which I'm coding in right now, is saying that `event` is deprecated. Is this correct? What is the new version then that I should be using. I tried `Event` but that didn't work.

Comment: If I suppose that you are using jquery your code shoud handle the event as parameter `$("#myElement").click(function (event) { 
  event.stopImmediatePropagation() 
 /* your code */
})`

Answer (score 0):

I found the accepted answer didn't work (likely outdated). Instead, I had to use the `event.stopPropagation();` method. Here's a link to the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).